# Partial application of JavaScript methods: how to retain th meaning of “this”

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, partials

In JavaScript, it’s pretty easy to define a partial application method for functions:

```
Function.prototype.partial = function partial() {
    var fn = this
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

    return function() {
        var newArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        return fn.apply(this, args.concat(newArgs))
    }
}
```

It works well for functions:

```
var biggerThanFive = Math.max.partial(5)
assert biggerThanFive(x) === Math.max(5, x)
```

But the resulting function’s “`this`” doesn’t stay the same as the original’s:

```
function Test() {
    this.name = 'test'
}

Test.prototype.a = function(b) {
    return [this.name, b]
}

var test = new Test()

test.a('x') // ['test','x']

var b = test.a.partial('y')
b() // [undefined,'y']
```

This can be fixed by manually binding the resulting function back to its original bound object:

```
var c = test.a.partial('z').bind(test)
c() //['test','z']
```

How to do this from within the `Function.prototype.partial` definition? `test.a` objiously knows that its “`this`” is “test”, so How can i access this knowledge?

---

What i learned from Esailija:

JavaScript doesn’t determine what “`this`” is inside a function at any other point than at calling time. `var d = [].concat` isn’t different from `var d = Array.prototype.concat`, and calling `d()` will call it on the global object because there’s nothing “on the left of it”.

Comment: This is an issue with the `this` keyword, not the "partial application" method that you've made up.  The value of `this` when calling `b()` will be the global scope (i.e. `window` in pretty much all browsers), and if there isn't a global variable named `name`, then you'll get `undefined` back.  To the browser, it isn't obvious that `test.a` is related to `b`, as it only appears as a variable with an anonymous function to the interpreter.

Comment: yeah, i know, that’s what i want to circumvent :) bind can do it, but i want to do it from within the partial method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You can do this with the built-in `.bind` method though, which is what you would eventually arrive at and settle with:

```
var b = test.a.bind(test, 'y')
b() 
//["test", "y"]
```

Comment: that’s what i feared… i don’t like the  subordinate clause though: i know a bout bind’s parallels with partiaö, but i still don’t get why a method that knows what its context is when doesn’t provide a reference to it. that’s a serious smell in JS’s language design…

Comment: @flyingsheep a function doesn't know its context because it's a first-class object and the `test.a` is merely a pointer to the object. Multiple variables and properties could then point to the same function without the function knowing what points at it. Even if it did know, what would be the correct context to choose?

Comment: the one it got bound to? so you’re saying that functions/methods only know what their “this” is going to point to as soon as they get called? that language is stupid!

Comment: @flyingsheep obviously a bound function knows what the `this` is and you can indeed use `bind` to bind a function. I was talking about unbound functions.

Comment: if `test.a` is a function defined by `Test.prototype.a = function() {…}; test = new Test()`, it is bound to `test`. I want to do something with that function while retaining its binding.

Comment: @flyingsheep no it's not bound to test objects in any way, `Test.prototype.a` is merely a pointer to an independent function *object*. If we give up functions as first class objects or enrich the syntax so that it's possible for some preprocessor to use `.bind` under to hood (e.g. ActionScript3), only then it is possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32490/discussion-between-flying-sheep-and-esailija)